# Are images in Next.js lazy loaded when visibility is set to hidden?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lazy-loading, nextjs-image

Are images in Next.js lazy loaded when visibility is set to hidden? If that is not the case I would want to make them lazy load. I know I can use the priority prop but I want them to load in a specified viewport position.

Comment: Images using `next/image` are only loaded when they enter the viewport by default. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization.

Comment: Are they loaded even if they have visibility hidden?

Answer (score 0):

All Images inside `Image components` in `Next js` are lazy loaded by default and it not going to change with visibility or other styling properties .
Only priority prop will change the behavior .

Also for more confidence I recommend you analyze the `Network` tab and see the behavior of your images.